# Parse Time into Calendar without losing Date part

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

I need to store in a `Calendar` Java object a date/time consisting of today's date plus a time parsed from a string in a `HH:mm:ss` format.

I tried creating a new `GregorianCalendar` and using `setTime()` to initialize it with the result of calling a `SimpleDateFormat`'s parse() method but then I noticed that `parse()` returns me a `Date` object with the correct parsed time but with the date of Jan 1, 1970.

For example:

```
String time = "23:32";
String timeFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Calendar todaysTime = new GregorianCalendar();

todaysTime.setTime(timeFmt.parse(time));
System.out.println(todaysTime.getTime());
```

Prints: `Thu Jan 01 11:32:00 CST 1970`
What I expected was: `Wed 03 11:32:00 CST 2015`

I can only see one alternative: Create a second `GregorianCalendar` with todays date and then set the year, month and day manually into `todaysTime` via `setYear()`, `setMonth()` and `setDayOfMonth()` but I hope there is a more elegant way to do that.

Can you help me look for a better way to parse the time part parsed into a `Date` object without losing the date part?

Comment: Do you *have* to use `Date` and `Calendar`? If you could use Joda Time or Java 8's `java.time` package, this and many other problems become much easier.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm stuck with Java 6 but if I can justify the use of Joda Time I think I can include it in my libray list!

Comment: Right. I would *strongly* advise you to that then - use Joda Time *everywhere* for your time/date handling. You'd parse your value to a `LocalTime`, and then it's easy enough to use that in a `DateTime` or a `LocalDateTime`. One word of warning though: if you're using `DateTime` (i.e. in a specific time zone) you should consider what you want to do if the resulting `DateTime` is ambiguous or skipped due to DST changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Date parsedDate = SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().parse(time);
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
instance.setTime( parsedDate );

Calendar result = Calendar.getInstance();
result.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, instance.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ) );
result.set( Calendar.MINUTE, instance.get( Calendar.MINUTE ) );
```

Comment: It seems a shorter way to do it compared to what I had in mind. However, I would still have to use a second Calendar object to store the parsed time and then set that parsed time to the original Calendar object.