# How to set Calendar object to current date but time from SimpleDateFormat that contains HH:mm:ss

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, simpledateformat

I need to create a new `Calendar` object that contains the current date but the time needs to be set from a given String of format `HH:mm:ss`.

I create a new calendar object with current date and time  and then use a `SimpleDateFormat` object to parse the string and set the time from that one but that only overwrites the calendar object with the parsed time and Jan 1 1970:

```
def currentTime = new java.util.Date();
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.setTime(currentTime);
java.util.Date inTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(initialTime);
calendar1.setTime(inTime);
```

Is there a way to get the values of Hour, Minute, Seconds and Milliseconds from the Date object to use it with `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)`, etc.?

Comment: Do you *have* to use java.util.* rather than java.time.*?

Comment: (There are various approaches here which will work, but moving away from java.util.Date/Calendar would definitely be cleanest.)

Comment: Using  java.time.* would be possible I think. My end goal is to be able to check if the current time is between start time and end time (both in HH:mm:ss format) with end time possibly after midnight (day+1), so I would need methods like calendar.after and calendar.before also from java.time.* somehow?

Comment: You should parse your value to a LocalTime, and then either create a ZonedDateTime or a LocalDateTime. Looks like Basil's getting you on the right track, but more context in the question would probably help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Time into Calendar without losing Date part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636017/parse-time-into-calendar-without-losing-date-part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
GregorianCalendar.from(                   // Converting from modern java.time class to troublesome legacy class. Do so only if you must. Otherwise use only the java.time classes.
    ZonedDateTime.of(                     // Modern java.time class representing a moment, a point on the timeline, with an assigned time zone through which to see the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region. 
        LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( “Pacific/Auckland” ) ) ,   // The current date in a particular time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. 
        LocalTime.of( 12 , 34 , 56 ) ,    // Specify your desired time-of-day. 
        ZoneId.of( “Pacific/Auckland” )   // Assign a time zone for which the date and time is intended. 
    )
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 34 , 56 ) ;  // 12:34:56
ZonedDateTime zdt =  ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

You can extract the time-of-day (or date) from an existing `ZonedDateTime`.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Best to avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes added before Java 8. But if you must, you can convert between the modern and legacy classes. Call on new methods added to the old classes.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;  // If you must, but better to avoid the troublesome old legacy classes.
```

Comment: Is it possible to do convert methods like calendar.after and calendar.before also to the new code? My end goal is to be able to check if the current time is between start time and end time (both in HH:mm:ss format) with end time possibly after midnight (day+1).

Comment: @reibuehl  Yes, the java.time classes are fully featured, including comparison methods such as `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual`. You can forget about `Calendar` & `Date` and never look back.  All this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search Stack Overflow before posting a Question. Tip: also search for “Half-Open” and “atStartOfDay”.

Comment: I converted my code to use java.time and can set the time there but the is Before seems to not work:
`    // Check if End Time is after midnight / the next day
    if (endTimeDate.isBefore(startTimeDate)) {
      endTimeDate.plusDays(1);
    }
`
does not add a day even thoug it should:
`Start:   06.02.2018 - 20:00:20
Current: 06.02.2018 - 22:57:45
End:     06.02.2018 - 04:00:04
`

Comment: @reibuehl The java.time classes use [*immutable objects*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), for thread-safety and simplicity. So `endTimeDate.plusDays(1)` has no effect on `endTimeDate`. The call produces a shiny new object that you need to capture. `ZonedDateTime dayLater = endTimeDate.plusDays(1) ;`. Spend some time (a) reading the Oracle Tutorial on java.time, and (b) searching and studying existing Stack Overflow posts.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering: when you’ve got a string in `HH:mm:ss` format, `LocalTime.parse("12:34:56")` converts it to the `LocalTime` object that goes into the code in the answer (no need for an explicit formatter)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps you.

```
    String hhmmss = "10:20:30";
    String[] parts = hhmmss.split(":");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();      
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
```

Comment: It doesn't help to perform the parsing, no... The OP has a string as input, and wants to combine the result of parsing that with today's date.

Comment: Please edit your answer rather than trying to *actually* supply the answer in comments - although if it uses `Integer.parseInt` I'd suggest that's probably not a great direction.

Comment: I will try this. Parsing the string manually might be the quickest solution as there is already a regex check that ensures that the format is HH:mm:ss.

Comment: This way seems to not work fully... the values for HOUR_OF_DAY, MINUTES and SECONDS are set but other values like time (the timestamp) and HOUR (the 12h value) are not updated, so I assume the whole object gets unusable this way.

Comment: Use Calendar.HOUR for 12 hrs format instead of Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY.

Answer (score 1):

Calendar objet Time is a java.util.Date object with the standard format. You can not set date with a specific format to your calendar.

To get the Date details (Hours, Minutes ...) try :

```
    final Date date = new Date(); // your date
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);

    final int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    final int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: While I agree that `Calendar` doesn't include a format, that's not what the OP actually wants to do. They want to take the current date, and only parse the *time* from the format string. (And your first sentence is at best confusing. A `java.util.Calendar` has more information than a `java.util.Date` does...)

Comment: And your edited code definitely doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The Edit is for responde on the question "Is there a way to get the values of Hour, Minute, Seconds and Milliseconds from the Date object to use it with calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)", I can explain more for you if you want.

Comment: Right, well you're calling it on the Calendar rather than the Date - which makes a certain amount of sense, but you're still definitely not answering the question IMO. I don't think this answer is going anywhere unless you address the OP's actual concern: taking a string in HH:mm:ss format, and trying to create a Calendar with today's date (presumably in the system time zone?) and the specified time of day.

Comment: Parsing date with `HH:mm:ss` format result a falsified date information and thats why we get `Jan 1 1970` as a parsed time.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. (I'd call it a default date rather than "falsified", but...) But the point is that that's the problem the OP is facing, and you're not currently addressing it.